# Request to drop collection on Mongodb from react frontend via express server sent twice

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my react project I have created a canvas that multiple users can update. I am using react, express and mongoose. When I want to clear the canvas I have a function clearDB() in the App.js component of my front end.

```
clearDB() 
    {
      alert('Clearing Database')
      return fetch(reseturl, {method: 'DELETE'})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          alert('Deleted:', res.message)
          return res
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
```

this is called by an event listener initiated in componentDidMount when the user presses 'z';

In the express server I have.

```
app.delete("/reset", function(req, res) {
  console.log("delete request sent ");
  db.dropCollection("dots", function (err, delOK) {

    if (err) {

        console.log("error delete collection");
        return res;
    } if (delOK) {

        console.log("delete collection success");
        return res;
    }
    return res
});
return res
});
```

The problem is that the collection is cleared immediately on pressing 'z', showing as an HTTP OPTIONS on the server output, and the again as a DELETE about a minute later.
This is the first output which appears as soon as the event listener picks up the keystroke.

```
OPTIONS /reset 204 0.320 ms - 0
delete request sent undefined
delete collection success<--(the log from the clearDB function)
GET /message 200 2.022 ms
```

Then about 2 minutes later

```
POST /message 200 2.293 ms - 16
DELETE /reset - - ms - -
delete request sent undefined
delete collection success<--(the log from the clearDB function, again!)
POST /message 200 372.026 ms - 16
```

The canvas gets cleared twice.Please help. No one else seems to have this problem!

Comment: adding res.end() to app.delete seems to have fixed this for now.

Answer (score 0):

The OPTIONS is only a pre-flight call that is sent to the back end to determine if your request is structured properly based on the back end. You can read more about the OPTIONS call [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS).

The DELETE call is what actually causes the code in your server's route handler to run.

So, if only one DELETE call is being sent for a single event, then that part is functioning correctly.

If, however, you still have an issue, it must be somewhere else in the code that you haven't posted.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. If it addressed your concern, please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ending the request with res.end() has stopped the unexpected behaviour.

`app.delete("/reset", function(req, res) { console.log("delete request sent ");
 db.dropCollection("dots", function (err, delOK) {

if (err) { console.log("error delete collection"); 
return res; }

if (delOK) { console.log("delete collection success"); 
return res; }

res.end();}); 
return res }); `